# How to Fetch the folders list from sugarsync in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory

I'm using the following code to get the list of folders in sugar sync .

```
-(void)listSugarSyncFiles:(id)sugarSyncDetails
{
   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sugarsync.com/user/8194615/folders/contents"];

   [[SugarSyncClient sharedInstance] getFolderWithURL:url completionHandler:^(SugarSyncFolder *aFolder, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error)
                           {
                             NSLog(@"folders is %@",aFolder.collections);

                           }                   

                         }];

}
```

The error getting for me is

```
[SugarSyncClient logErrorWithHttpResponse:responseData:] + 184 - Error code 699, get folder failed, (Data was expected but not returned by the server (error 699))
2014-10-02 16:19:22.762 sugar[1572:60b] [SugarSyncClient logErrorWithHttpResponse:responseData:] + 255 - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><collectionContents end="1" hasMore="false" start="0"><collection type="syncFolder"><displayName>My SugarSync</displayName><ref>https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:8194615:2</ref><contents>https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:8194615:2/contents</contents></collection><collection type="syncFolder"><displayName>Pdf_sugarSync</displayName><ref>https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:8194615:49100884_15025</ref><contents>https://api.sugarsync.com/folder/:sc:8194615:49100884_15025/contents</contents></collection></collectionContents>
```